# Thread throttling with SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, semaphore

I want to ensure that only one thread calls the service at a time, discarding the later ones while first one is still executing.

```
  await throttler.WaitAsync();
        T result = default(T);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.Proxy.PostAsJsonAsync(path, request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            throttler.Release();
        }
        else
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
        return result;
```

In constructor I have  `throttler = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);`

Only a single request is being sent to the server at a time. However I also want to kill all the later request if a request is still executing.

Comment: _"Can it be achieved by using SemaphoreSlim class"_ -- probably. Impossible to say without a good [mcve] in your question, and "can it be done?" questions are inherently too broad anyway. But a semaphore with an initial count of 1, you can use `Wait(0)` to attempt to acquire the semaphore immediately; if you fail to acquire it, you know the task is already executing and can skip it. Don't forget to use `finally` to ensure you release the semaphore when the task completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WaitAsync(TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462723(v=vs.110).aspx) to discard other calls when a thread is already calling the service:

```
bool entered = await semaphore.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
if (entered) {
    try {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.Proxy.PostAsJsonAsync(path, request);
    }
    finally {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
else {
    // Discarded: Another service call is in progress    
}
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho if the semaphore is already full, the method will return false immediately and doesn't wait for it.

Comment: I know that. Put another way, the call will always return immediately. So, I ask you again: why await the call?

Comment: @PeterDuniho so you will be happy If I use Wait(0) instead? there is no difference since the calling method needs to be async anyway. But if you want to change Zero to 1ms later, you don't need to change method name later.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I want to discard the other calls when a thread is already calling the service.

Comment: @VaibhavJain The is what the code do. If the WaitAsync method returns false (another thread calling the service) "entered" variable will be false and the call will be discarded.